# Validation POST request by OAuth1.0a in Django

Tags: python, django, oauth, hmac, sha

I'm using Django 3.0.7 and i need to validate the incoming POST request from my partner server by HMAC-SHA1 or OAuth1.0a and if it validated send response `{"OK":"200"}`.
My views.py looks like this:

```
def api_create_blog_view(request):

    blog_post = BlogPost(author=request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = BlogPostSerializer(blog_post, data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({"response_code":"OK"})
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

There are a lot of topics how to do it, but i can't get how to do it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I answered your other question, I think this is what you really want. You want to create an OAuth 1.0 provider, but you don't need to issue client id and secrets.

Here is the documentation on create an OAuth 1.0 provider: https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/django/1/index.html